# Spring mvc and angularjs with spring security ajax login

Tags: java, ajax, spring, angularjs, spring-security

i want  my angular-spring app to be secured, my angular side acts like the frontend and spring mvc is the backend or server side, all if fine but i have a problem using javaConfig based Spring security when an url is not allowed, the idea is to show an error dialog and then "redirect" (but using router in angular) to the login page partial.

the problem is when i use formLogin() in my security config i always get the provided spring login form, but i don't want that form shows because all my request are done using AJAX and i have my own login.html; following is the security config method:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.debug("CONFIGURE SECURITY HTTP");
        /*.csrf().disable()*/
        http
        .formLogin()
            .successHandler(ajaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
            .failureHandler(ajaxAuthenticationFailureHandler)
            .permitAll()
        .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(customLoginAuthenticationEntryPoint).and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(Constants.VIEWS_PATH+"**").permitAll().anyRequest().anonymous()
                .accessDecisionManager(customAccessDecisionManager);

        //super.configure(http);

}
```

Here i want to use formLogin option by the Handlers, this handlers only return a json indicating to my frontend that the user is login or not (`{login:true}`), so my questions are, what i'm doing is a good practice or there is another option and is posible to disable the deafault login form in spring?, i read about using token based authentication like in this [link](https://github.com/philipsorst/angular-rest-springsecurity) but i don't know if they are using async request and if its a good practice.